# Decent e-commerce solution for a small number of items?

Tags: php, drupal, e-commerce

I'm sure this gets asked a lot in these parts, but I'm currently running an Ubercart install on drupal6 (non-dev releases) and I keep running in to little problems that are making me want to switch to a different platform. I've used magento before on some client sites, but that is way too heavy for what I'm trying to do. In fact, I feel like drupal might be a bit too much, as I'm only selling a few products (2-3). I was contemplating upgrading to d7 and running Ubercart again, but I hear d7 is even slower than d6.

So my question to you, seasoned ecommerce veterans, is there a pretty light-weight ecom solution aimed at only selling a few products? I would like to have something that has link tracking, google analytics integration, shipping options (USPS/UPS), and authorize.net integration.

I don't need a giant catalogue of products. In fact, I'll probably be customizing each product page sepperately. I have been poking around for a few days and am looking for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try 
Wordpress + wp-ecommerce(a shopping cart plugin for wordpress)

or

Joomla + Virtuemart (An ecommerce component for Joomla)

Both combinations are easy to setup.

Comment: Most of those only use authorize.net SIM don't they? so you are taken off the page to do your orders? I looked at both of those months ago, but maybe things have changed a bit.

Comment: if you want user to stay on your website and pay right there, you can use paypal, https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/website-payments-pro

Comment: I already have authorize.net set up. So I'd prefer to use that. Also how much through-put can joomla/wp handle?

Comment: Joomla/Virtuemart might be easy to set up but Virtuemart is a poorly written application. Best to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nice Drupal Commerce project http://www.drupalcommerce.org/

Quite simple, and functional.